# Samsung Galaxy S5 not connecting PC

Tags: usb, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I've been unable to connect my samsung galaxy s5 to pc despite having tried for a couple of hours.

I was able to connect to the same pc with a different s5 a few days ago and have tried connecting it to a different PC so the problem is definitely with the mobile, although I have tried installing drivers on PC.
Phone doesn't even show up in device manager.
The option to use the phone as a usb modem is greyed out as it says it is not connected to a PC.
The phone is charging notification doesn't show either.
I've tried different usb cables and different usb ports.
USB debugging is turned on, USB is configured to MDB + ATP (i tried changing it to other things then swapping back but it won't even let me change)
I've updated the phone's os.

If anyone has any other ideas would love to hear them as I need this working for debugging purposes.

Comment: The notification bar doesn't come down?

Comment: the notification bar comes down but the notification that the phone is charging doesn't (despite it charging, obviously)

Comment: Ah, ok. So the problem might certainly lies with your USB connector, this would need a cleaning or even a replacement